# Why type field cann't queryed from salesforce task object

Tags: apex, tasks

If we query type field

> SELECT Type FROM Task

It will thorough the error as "No such type of column 'Type' on entity 'Task'".

But if we see in the App Setup->Customize->Activities->Task Fields

We will find 'type' field as picklist

Answer (score 3):

Check field level security settings to make sure its not being hidden.

Comment: Yes,you are right but why it is not enabled by default

Comment: @Superfell, I actually find this contradictory to what docs suggest. As per docs `Apex generally runs in system context; that is, the current user's permissions, field-level security, and sharing rules aren’t taken into account during code execution.` If we use "with sharing", still in that case as well as per docs `Enforcing sharing rules by using the with sharing keyword doesn’t enforce the user's permissions and field-level security. Apex code always has access to all fields and objects in an organization, ensuring that code won’t fail to run because of hidden fields or objects for a user.`

Comment: So why would the Type field not be accessible in the query? Am i thinking too much or is there any reason to the field not being accessible?

Comment: that only applies to triggers.

Answer (score 0):

I know it seems crazy but we can't report on the std field Type of the Activities/Task. So only WorkAround is by creating a custom Type field to use it in reports.

ref. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000394194&type=1

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE!  Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.